# How we can use multithreading for sending a POST request to URL with headers in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import requests
#Making session
m1 = requests.Session()
#URL And DAta
url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/python/demopage.php'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}
#Creating connection an sending request
x = m1.post(url, data = myobj)
#printing response

print(x)
```

Comment: Why would you use multithreading if you have only one request? If you have multiple requests, update your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```py
import threading
import requests

list_of_links = [
    # All your links and headers here in tuples
]

threads = []

all_html = {
    # This will be a dictionary of the links as key and the Response object of the links as values
}


def get_html(link, headers):
    r = requests.post(link, data=headers)
    all_html[link] = r


for link, header in list_of_links:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=get_html, args=(link, header))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
   
for t in threads:
    t.join()
    
print(all_html)

print("DONE")
```

Comment: Have you looked at class `ThreadPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` module? What if you had 1000 URLs to post but felt that perhaps 1000 threads might be excessive and having a concurrency of, for example, 50 threads was more appropriate?

Comment: More efficient to create a `requests` `Session` object, put the header in that, and pass the Session object to `get_html` and let `get_html` do the post using the `Session` object, especially if the URLs involve the same website. `Session` objects use connection pooling. See [Session Objects](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Comment: Actually, I want to send min 1000 request to URL with headers more quickly. i don't want to send requests to multiple URL.